# Accessing values from Python sub-dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, request

I've scraped a webpage using an API and want to access one part of the results, but am having difficulty accessing it:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'x-api-key': 'my_key'}
test_url= "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/date/2018-05- 
22.json"
resp = requests.get(test_url, headers=headers).json()
```

The results are coming out in a dictionary format that looks like this:

```
[{'chamber': 'Senate',
          'congress': 115,
          'party': 'R',
          'state': 'NC',
          'url': 'url1_goes_here'},
{'chamber': 'Senate',
          'congress': 115,
          'party': 'R',
          'state': 'ND',
          'url': 'url2_goes_here'}]
```

I want to extract the 'url' value from each entry, but the entries doesn't seem to have a key by which I can drill down. How can I go about accessing these? I thought that:

```
resp["url]
```

Would work, but I didn't have any luck. The output I'd ideally want would be something like:

```
[url1, url2]
```

Comment: After trying out your code I figured out what's propably your problem. your request returns `{'message': None}` for me so there will obviously an error when you try to get `url` which isn't there. [The site](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api) also shows you need an api key so if you haven't one you need to sign up to get your actual data from the api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was able to get this working with:

```
for each in resp['results']:
print(each['url'])
```

Comment: Had you indicated that the list in your question was under the `'result'` key, we could have included it in our answers. For now `resp['result']` is pure magic given the current state of the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a list of dicts. So you have to first get the elements of that list, before you can treat them as dicts.

For example, the first URL is `results[0]['url']`. Or, if you want to do something with every URL, you have to do 'for result in results: dosomething(result['url'])`.

So, what if you want to get a list of all the URLs?

```
urls = []
for result in results:
    url = result['url']
    results.append(url)
```

Of course you can make this more compact if you understand list comprehensions:

```
urls = [result['url'] for result in results]
```

---

If you're going to be doing a lot of complicated lookups on this structure, there are two options to consider.

---

First, you can restructure the data into a form that's easier to use. For example, if you're going to need to do a lot of things like look up the senator from North Dakota, it would be nice if you could write `senate['ND']` instead of `[result for result in results if result['state'] == 'ND' and result['chamber'] == 'Senate']`. You can do that with:

```
senate = {result['state']: result for result in results if result['chamber'] == 'Senate'}
house = {result['state']: result for result in results if result['chamber'] == 'House'}
```

Obviously this is complicated, and it's only useful if it saves you more complexity elsewhere, multiple times.

---

There are also (at least) three different mini-languages for searching nested-list-and-dict structures with key paths as strings, with wildcards—jsonpath, dpath, and kvc—and they all have libraries on PyPI you can look for. They all have a bit of a learning curve, and are overkill if you're just doing one simple search on the data. But if you're going to be doing a lot of searches, the fact that you can write each one as, say, `urls = search(results, '*.url')` instead of `urls = [result['url'] for result in results]` can sometimes pay off.

Comment: Similar to above, when I try to call: `urls = [resp['url'] for resp in resp]` I get thrown `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"` ? @abarnert

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract each URL in turn out of your `resp` list. A simple list-comprehension would do:

```
urls = [entry['url'] for entry in resp]
```

Comment: This makes sense, but is throwing me an error `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"`? @mathias

Comment: @sabrina if `resp` is indeed what you posted in the question, this shouldn't. Are you sure `resp` is a list of dictionaries?